# Converting a Firefox add-on to scratchpad format

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk, jsctypes

Debugging Firefox add-on in scratchpad returns some errors in following cases:

1. Using require
2. Defining some GUI such as icons, buttons and etc.
3. Interacting with another pages (i.e. content scripts)
4. (Possibility some other cases)

---

Consider the following example which [`Get Cursor Position`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/js-ctypes/Using_js-ctypes/Standard_OS_Libraries):

```
Components.utils.import("resource://gre/modules/ctypes.jsm");
var lib = ctypes.open("user32.dll");

/* note: if you go to GetCursorPos page on MSDN, it says first argument is of structure POINT, so lets create that structure,
 * the link here shows that that x and y are type Long which is ctypes.long
 */
// https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd162805%28v=vs.85%29.aspx
var POINT = new ctypes.StructType("tagPOINT", [
  { "x": ctypes.long },
  { "y": ctypes.long }
]);

/* Declare the signature of the function we are going to call */
var GetCursorPos = lib.declare('GetCursorPos',
    ctypes.winapi_abi,
    ctypes.bool,
    POINT.ptr
);

/* Use it like this */
var point = POINT();
var ret = GetCursorPos(point.address());

Components.utils.reportError(ret);
Components.utils.reportError(point);

lib.close();
```

Any helps to editing and completing the question with better examples or something else, would be appreciated.

Comment: You should execute all ctypes from a ChromeWorker for performance. Like we did here remember - https://github.com/Noitidart/jpm-chromeworker/ - you can do ctypes on main thread, but for complicated ctypes it can lock up the thread. In some cases you have to do it on the mainthread, but always try do do as much as possible from ChromeWorker's. You can use PromiseWorker, it's easier for communication - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/PromiseWorker

Answer (score 1):

For SDK addons I would recommend using [jpm watchpost + extension auto installer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/Tools/jpm#Developing_without_browser_restarts) instead.

That will automatically create an xpi and reinstall it in your browser every time you save a file. Simply keeping the browser console open will get you any potential error outputs.

> Interacting with another pages (i.e. content scripts)

The browser toolbox's scratchpad can select the target environment in which it is executed

> Using require

In chrome contexts require can be imported via `let { require } = Cu.import("resource://gre/modules/commonjs/toolkit/require.js")`

If you use the addon debugger I think the addon's require should be available